# Regular expression works on some servers and not others

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble debugging a regular expression. First, the code (this is the complete file... sorry for the lack of line breaks -- see http://pastebin.com/h5CeiY5F for a pastebin):

```
<?php
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('#" FirstDownType="[A-Z][0-9]+"/><Play PlayDescription="Penalty[^<]+/>#', '<Play DownDistanceYardline="3-1-GB 7" EarnedFirstDown="False" PlayDescription="(3:40) 71-C.Brown reported in as eligible. 28-M.Ingram left guard to GB 7 for no gain (94-J.Wynn; 95-H.Green)."/><Play DownDistanceYardline="4-1-GB 7" EarnedFirstDown="False" PlayDescription="(3:10) 9-D.Brees pass incomplete short left to 23-P.Thomas."/><Play Header="Green Bay Packers at 3:02"/><Play DownDistanceYardline="1-10-GB 7" EarnedFirstDown="False" PlayDescription="(3:02) 44-J.Starks right tackle to GB 11 for 4 yards (94-C.Jordan)."/><Play DownDistanceYardline="2-6-GB 11" EarnedFirstDown="False" PlayDescription="(2:26) 12-A.Rodgers pass deep right to 85-G.Jennings pushed ob at GB 33 for 22 yards (33-J.Greer)." FirstDownType="P17"/><Play PlayDescription="Penalty on NO-33-J.Greer, Defensive Pass Interference, declined."/><Play DownDistanceYardline="1-10-GB 33" EarnedFirstDown="True" PlayDescription="(2:01) (Shotgun) 12-A.Rodgers pass short left to 85-G.Jennings to GB 47 for 14 yards (21-P.Robinson)." FirstDownType="P18"/><Play DownDistanceYardline="1-10-GB 47" EarnedFirstDown="True" PlayDescription="(1:22) 12-A.Rodgers pass short right to 87-J.Nelson pushed ob at NO 44 for 9 yards (27-M.Jenkins)."/><Play DownDistanceYardline="2-1-NO 44" EarnedFirstDown="False" PlayDescription="(:47) 44-J.Starks right tackle to NO 42 for 2 yards (51-J.Vilma; 94-C.Jordan)." FirstDownType="R19"/><Play DownDistanceYardline="1-10-NO 42" EarnedFirstDown="True" PlayDescription="(:07) 25-R.Grant right tackle to NO 40 for 2 yards (51-J.Vilma, 58-S.Shanle)."/><QuarterSummary Team="New Orleans Saints" Score="27" TimeOfPossession="10:47" FirstDownsRushing="3" FirstDownsPassing="5" FirstDownsPenalty="1" FirstDownsTotal="9" ThirdDownEfficiency="1/3" FourthDownEfficiency="0/1"/><QuarterSummary Team="Green Bay Packers" Score="35" TimeOfPossession="4:13" FirstDownsRushing="1" FirstDownsPassing="2" FirstDownsPenalty="0" FirstDownsTotal="3" ThirdDownEfficiency="0/1" FourthDownEfficiency="0/0"/>', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

When I run this on several sandboxes (like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ or functions-online.com/preg_match.html ), it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => " FirstDownType="P17"/><Play PlayDescription="Penalty on NO-33-J.Greer, Defensive Pass Interference, declined."/> )
```

That's the expected output I'm looking for.

However, when I run it on my server (and I've tested it on two different servers), I get:

```
Array ( [0] => " FirstDownType="P17"/> )
```

All I can think of is that preg_match changed between PHP 5.3.10 (the version on the sandbox) and PHP 5.3.6 (our version), or that our Ubuntu version is misconfigured?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot be bother to add those line breaks, why should I be bothered to download from pastebin and find the bug?

Comment: It does match - but I had to look in source code to see the full match, because the browser attempts to parse it as HTML. Also, you really shouldn't be attempting to parse tagged structures via REGEX. Use DOM methods.

Comment: @Utkanos - +1 for patience. Why cannot some people ask a question where no horizontal scroll-bars are involved?

Comment: Exactly what info do you want to extract from this XML?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to match this using a regex?  How about using an XML parser instead?

Try using [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to get the node(s) you need.

```
$sXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml>'.$xml.'</xml>');
```

Then you can use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to find the element(s) you need.

```
$play = $sXML->xpath('//Play[starts-with(@PlayDescription, "Penalty")]/preceding-sibling::Play[@FirstDownType]');
```

This will select the `Play` element preceding the `Play` element that has a `PlayDescription` starting with `"Penalty"`.

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ECQKcB

Comment: I'm actually using DOM for the majority of the processing... I'm trying to preprocess it first, though. That's why I'm using regexes here.

Comment: @AndrewMin: "Pre-process it"... what exactly are you trying to do?  Can't DOM do what you want without needing regex?